# Google AppsScript - Specify Script Scopes (for REST API calls)

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, user-permissions

I work a lot with AppsScript within my workplace. I've built lots of custom `OAuth2.0` flows within AppsScript, that allow the application to call Google's REST APIs, and I've also worked with enabling the 'built in' API interaction objects (GmailApp, CalendarApp, etc). If you enable any of the built in APIs, the script editor adds the relevant scopes to the project information, and then asks the user for permission to interact with these APIs, when the web app first loads.

If I need to interact with both REST APIs and the few built in API calling objects, the user needs to first grant permission to the built in API scopes, then has to follow a separate `OAuth` flow, for the REST APIs. This makes for a really ugly user experience.

Is there a way to add REST API scopes to the list of scopes within the project information, so that when the user first loads the app, it asks them to grant permission for ALL scopes that the project will need? I could then retrieve the users oauth token from the script session with `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`, and use that in all external REST API calls.

EDIT (~12:00:05 18/DEC/15):

Please note, I already know how to enable APIs through the Developer Console Project that's linked to the AppsScript project - I want to find a way to add ALL APIs that are enabled to the Scripts properties, so that when the user launches the app, it asks them to grant permission to access all enabled APIs on their behalf (even REST apis), so that I don't need a second manual OAuth flow / token for the REST APIs.

EDIT (~14:00:08 18/DEC/15):

I've also looked into the Import/Export functionality within Drive, documented here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export
and can't find any way to alter the scopes (or supply any scopes) for the project, this way.

Answer (score 0):

In apps script you can enable specific API if you go to the menu "Resources > Advanced Google Services". It will open a Popup with a list of API, but there you also have the option to go to the Developer Console with the project associated with your Apps Script project.

And from there you can get the necessary information (clientId, etc.) related to the same Apps Script project and use it in you OAuth flow.

If you already have a project with all the required configurations and all the necessary API already enabled, you can also link your current Apps Script project to that app, so you don't have to do the same again.

In the menu "Resources > Developer Console Project", a popup will open and there you will have the option to access the Developer Console, but also you will have the option to associate the current Apps Script project to any other app you already have.

Just keep in mind that when you are trying to use an API you will have to enable it in the "Advanced Google Services", both in the list that the popup shows as well as in the Developer Console.

After doing this, the access tokens will be related to the same app and the users will grant permissions only one time when enabling a new API.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm aware that you have to enable APIs within the 'Advanced Google Services' section. This all works fine, and allows you to create a manual OAuth flow using the Client ID and Secret - but it doesn't add the scopes of the enabled APIs to the Script properties - and doesn't prompt the user for permission to interact with those APIs (on behalf of the user) when the web application starts.

I need a way to add the additional API scopes to the script properties, so that when the user launches the web app, it asks them to grant the app permission to ALL APIs (even REST apis), that are enabled.

Comment: If the api that you need is in the list of the "Advances Google Services", after enabling it, you can use the service related. eg. after enabling Google Apps Activity API (also in the Developer Console), in your script you can use the service 'AppsActivity' and the scopes related will be added. But you have to add it in the script so it is recognized. Are you trying to use an API not supported in Apps Script?

Comment: A good example is Google Cloud Resource Manager API. If I wanted to make a web application that runs on behalf of the user, and reads the Cloud Resources they have access to, then emails them with GmailApp, I can enable Gmail in Advanced Google Services, but there's no way to let the script know I'm planning on using Cloud Resource Manager API (via UrlFetchApp), so it won't add the scopes to the list of scopes (unde File > Project properties), and won't ask the user for permission to access this API. I need a way to let the script know I plan to use this API, so it will ask the user.